# SQL retrieve all rows between two dates and a specific number of rows before the date ordered by date

Tags: mysql, sql, union, between

As the title says, I have a table with a date column. I am trying to retrieve all rows between 2 dates as well as X number of rows before the beginning date ordered by date.

Take a select * from table order by date DSC

```
20200201
20200101
20191201
20191101
20191001
20190901
20190801
20190701
```

I want between 20200201 and 20191201 and the previous 3 rows(not knowing the date)

```
result
20200201
20200101
20191201
20191101
20191001
20190901
```

my current query returns a random set of high dates between the union for some reason:

```
(SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Date BETWEEN 20200201 AND 20191201 ORDER BY Date ASC)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Date < 20191201 ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 3)
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: How many rows of results are you getting? Your 'Date BETWEEN'-coditions seem backwards to me, which should give you 0 results, leavin only 3 rows of results from the bottom part of the join. Please be ware, I've never used Postgres SQL though.

Comment: Sorry it is Mysql.  I switched the between dates and it really changed the query for the worse. It gave me SOME of the first select and 1 from the second select

Comment: Add ORDER BY at the end, to sort the UNION's result. (The result set order from a subquery is not kept outside the subquery.) And perhaps switch to UNION ALL.

Comment: Sorry took so long to get back. The issue was as jarlh pointed out, the order of the subquery's were not kept(thats why things were jumbled) and a simple ORDER BY of the whole UNION fixed this. I did not try Gordon's response as this solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

I tried this query and it worked for me:

```
(SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Date BETWEEN  20191201 AND 20200201 ORDER BY Date ASC)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Date < 20191201 ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 3)
```

The first select shows me:

```
20191201
20200101
20200201
```

The second select shows me:

```
20191101 
20191001 
20190901
```

Comment: Yes both queries select what I want, and I can add them programatically however I would like to get it just from the query.

Comment: Sorry @James, I don't quite understand your problem. The union works fine for me. I get those six rows. Could you please provide more details about your issue? Note: please be aware I switched your parameter dates in the first query.

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(date, 3) over (order by date) as next_date_3
      from t
     ) t
where (date < '202o-02-01' and (next_date_3 >= '2020-02-01' or next_date_3 is null) ) or
      (date between '2020-02-01' and '2019-12-01')
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was as jarlh pointed out, the order of the subquery's were not kept(thats why things were jumbled) and a simple ORDER BY of the whole UNION fixed this. I did not try Gordon's response as this solved my issue so:

```
(SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Date BETWEEN  20191201 AND 20200201)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Date < 20191201 ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 3)
ORDER BY Date ASC
```

Thank you